# How to create a mapping where the key is pointing to an array that I can push items into it?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to create a mapping where the key is an ID and it is pointing to an array of dates. The idea is to enter a date everytime the ID comes to the facility so I can have an array of dates next to the ID
I created a struct with a uint VDates and a mapping with a uint key and pointing to the struct but as an array

```
struct visitDates{
    uint VDates;
}
    mapping (uint => visitDates[]) public dates;
```

This is the add date function where I set the key as secret number and push the date entry into the array

```
function AddVisitDate (uint _date, uint _SecretNum ) public {
           dates[_SecretNum].push(visitDates(_date));
       }
```

The problem is in getVisitDate function where the idea is to pass the secret number and I call the mapping and I need it to return the array containing the dates of visit of that secret number i dont not know how to write this function so if u have any suggestion please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function would look like this, just use the secret number to get the mapped value:

```
    function getVisitDate (uint _SecretNum ) public view returns( visitDates[] memory){
           return dates[_SecretNum];
}
```